# What are some other comparable products to RealBasic?

Tags: realbasic

I'm looking to get something that can create apps for Mac and Windows. It also seems that RealBasic can also create applications that have some sort of SQLLite DB built in. This is nice for standalone apps that need to save state/data.

I have Flash, which can create executables for Mac and Windows, but it doesn't have the easy database packaging or integration.

What are some other comparable products like RealBasic?

Answer (score 5):

You can check out [LiveCode](http://www.runrev.com/products/livecode/livecode-platform-overview/)

I do not have any experience using it but it also claims to support cross platform application development across Mac / Windows / Linux etc

Also, i think this product is what used to be called "Revolution" so it has been around atleast for a few years now - Revolution has been around since before 2001 to the best of my knowledge

Comment: The syntax for LiveCode is very similar to Lingo (Director...formerly by Macromedia, now Adobe :) )

Comment: As it turns out LiveCode and Lingo are both descendants of Hypercard. I loved Lingo. Now I'm tempted by LiveCode. The one thing that makes it costly is that you need to pay to deploy to each platform.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with using Java is that the UI won't have the native look and feel of the platform it's running on. Sometimes that won't matter. But I've found that for most endusers the UI is a big deal.

Contrary to the above answer, RealBasic has never used an "interpreted runtime". It's compiled to machine code and linked to the runtime. These days it's compiled into [LLVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Level_Virtual_Machine) instructions first before being compiled into machine code. So it's definitely faster than Java. It's main weakness seems to be the stigma attached to any language based on Basic.

Answer (score 2):

I was using [RealBasic](http://www.realsoftware.com/) for many years, due to its cross-platform capabilities. RealBasic was very long the only product that really managed both worlds.

With OS X 10.4 [JAVA](http://www.java.com/) became a real alternative for RealBasic. On Windows JAVA was running well for several years, and with 10.4 it was also running well on OS X now.
The only thing with JAVA is: You need to have a JRE on the target system (OS X always has, Windows usually has but not always) - that is the only bad thing about JAVA. RealBasic is also "only an Interpreted runtime" - but it brings it's runtime in the binary, what on the other hand makes RealBasic .exe really huge if you compare them to a [VB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic)-project.

With 10.4 I decided to change to JAVA for Crossplatform-Development and from my point of view today, it was the best decission I could make.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Adobe Flex (now Apache Flex)

Flex for Web Apps (RIA apps) using web services (php, coldfusion, java, asp.net, etc)
AIR for Desktop (Windows, Mac)
AIR for mobile (Android, iOS, BlackBerry)

if you use AIR, then you need install AIR runtime

sorry for my bad english